# Access sql statement with multiple sums and joins

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get the sum of two different fields from different tables but no matter what i do one of the fields gets doubled. Below is my statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

```
SELECT subq.[Opportunity ID], 
       sum(subq.[Buy Price]) as [Buy Price], 
       sum(subq.ProjectAmt) as [ProjectAmt]
FROM ( SELECT Distinct s.[Opportunity ID] as [Opportunity ID], 
                       s.[Buy Price] as [Buy Price], 
                       i.[ProjectAmt] as [ProjectAmt]
       FROM SF_SKU_Data s
       Inner join [ProjectInvoice] i on i.[Opportunity ID] = s.[Opportunity ID]
       Group by  s.[Opportunity ID],  s.[Buy Price], i.[ProjectAmt]
     ) AS subq
GROUP BY subq.[Opportunity ID]
```

Comment: Is your join one-to-one, or is it possibly a one-to-many?  i.e. do you have multiple rows in ProjectInvoice or SF_SKU_Data for each Oppurtunity ID?